# Extracting single cell from postgres table using Python

Tags: python, postgresql

How can I select only 1 cell in a table created from a Postgres database?

Here is my code.

```py
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd

conn = psycopg2.connect(host="…", port = "….", database="….", user="…..", password="…..")

if conn is not None*:
    print('Connection ON')
else:
    print('Connection not established to PostgreSQL.')

table = conn.cursor()
table.execute("SQL CODE...")
```

Assuming this is my generated table in SQLcode

[image: table]

How do I just refer to the L element for example?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. This looks like a basic question about SQL and psycopg2. Have you tried [a SQL tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/) and [the psycopg2 tutorial](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html)? If so, what did you try that didn't work?

Comment: Thx for answer..
I've tried these links several times
I'm editing the post and including my attempts!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1) I do not see any actual attempts at a query. 2) I would suggest working in the Postgres command line client `psql` first to learn how to create a query.  3) The use of the term `cell` implies you are thinking of the database as a spreadsheet, it is not. You need to think in terms of fields and values. 4) Given 1) & 2) I would try in `psql` the query: `select * from <the_table> where size = 'L'`. If the field name is actually `Size` then: `... "Size" = 'L'`